# How to open ios native controller by plugin before return value?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have created one plugin class for iPhone by using `phonegap`
and I would like to add a native viewcontroller when the plugin receives message from phone gap

```
[self.viewController show:json];
```

the functione show in MainViewController:

```
-(void)show:(NSDictionary*)options{
    NSLog(@"show");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:cView];
}
```

However, the issue is the screen displayed only "show" but the Subview did not appeared，It shows after `[self writeJavascript:javaScript]` when it goes back to phonegap window.plugins. Success msg received.

My question is how to return message to phonegap after subview end.

How can I do?